# Not able to install npm packages / angular-cli

Tags: node.js, angular-cli

I have tried almost everything but not able to just run the simple command:

```
npm install -g angular-cli
```

I too updated the node to the latest version i.e **v7.4.0**
and npm to version: **4.0.5**

I tried to check the proxy setting but I am not behind any firewall setting and trying to run this from a home laptop.

Please check the image for error.

[image]

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? Do you have some internet security on? Maybe the connection is blocked

Comment: Are you able to open `https://www.npmjs.com/` on your browser?

Comment: I am not behind any firewall/proxy @fdelia and I am able to open as well as ping npmjs.com santanu